# Issue with ggplot and geom_bar: want two columns to stack without adding together

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'm making a bar graph showing how many votes and candidate got in two elections. I want the values stacked, but the values are adding together to make the y axis bigger than it should be. So for example, in the x=23 spot, the 2018 value should only be about 800. the 2019 value is correct, but the two are being added together to make the 2019 value bigger than it should be.

[image]

I don't understand how to get it so that it shows me the 2018 value with the 2019 value stacked inside of it without adding the two together.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
ggplot(data = OverallMcCreadyVotes, aes(x=precinct_abbrv, y=McCready,fill=year)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(
    breaks = c("2019","2018"),
    values = c("dark blue","light blue")
  )
```

Comment: I'm confused. If you don't want the bars to total up to some combined value, why are you stacking them? Do you mean you want one bar placed in front of the other? You can do that with `position = "identity"`, but I can't imagine that not being misleading. If they shouldn't add up, don't display them as though they do—find a more appropriate visualization, such as dodged bars

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want `stacked bar` but with no addition of values from 2018 to 2019.

One possible trick (maybe other tricks exists, it's the first one that came up in my mind) to do it is to manipulate your values from 2019 to get them to be the difference between 2019 and 2018. Like that, once your values will be plotted as `stack` you will have not the sum of values but the actual values of 2019.

Let me explain with this example (it's from the `mtcars` dataset that I twisted a little bit to make it prettier):

```r
library(tidyverse)
d = mtcars[1:20,]
d <- d %>% group_by(cyl, gear) %>% summarize(M = mean(disp))
d[5,] <- c(8,4,150)
d[6,] <- c(4,3,240)
> d
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   cyl [3]
    cyl  gear     M
* <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     4     4  104.
2     6     3  242.
3     6     4  164.
4     8     3  365.
5     8     4  150 
6     4     3  240
```

If we are plotting as you did with your code, we will get:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(x = cyl, y = M, fill = as.factor(gear)))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

we can eventually use `position_dodge(0)` with some transparency, but the color are not really nice:

```r
ggplot(d, aes(x = cyl, y = M, fill = as.factor(gear)))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0), alpha = 0.4)
```

[image]

So, as I mentionned, we can eventually, manipulate values from `gear = 3`, to make them being `gear 3 = gear3- gear4`, we can do it using `tidyr` and `dplyr`. (There is most likely easier way to achieve this result but it's the one that came first in my mind, it is just to show you the idea of what we should obtain)

```r
library(tidyverse)
d %>% group_by(cyl) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = "gear", values_from = "M") %>%
  mutate(Gear4 = `4`, Gear3 = `3`) %>% mutate(Gear3 = Gear3 - Gear4) %>% select(cyl, Gear4, Gear3) %>%
  pivot_longer(., -cyl, names_to = 'Gear', values_to = "Mean") 

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   cyl [3]
    cyl Gear   Mean
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1     4 Gear4 104. 
2     4 Gear3 136. 
3     6 Gear4 164. 
4     6 Gear3  77.7
5     8 Gear4 150  
6     8 Gear3 215.
```

Now, if you are plotting them, you will get:

```r
ggplot(d, aes(x = as.factor(cyl), y = Mean, fill = Gear)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

And you get a stacked barplot with no sum of values from `gear = 3` and `gear = 4`.

However this example will work only if all your values from `Gear 3` will be superior to values from `Gear 4`. Otherwise, you will have some weird barplot.

For your example, my personal opinion is to represent it as a `geom_line`:

```r
ggplot(d, aes(x = cyl,  y = M, color = as.factor(gear))) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?